# Null pojo with @BeanParam

Tags: java, api, rest, annotations, resteasy

I am trying to use @BeanParam with RESTEasy so that I can use swagger docs.

I have annotated my POJOs with @QueryParam.

I have gotten it to work successfully with a POST method, but am having major issues with GET

The object passed in is null no matter what I try.

Here is my pojo

```
  public class TestObject {
        @QueryParam("test1")
        private String test1;



        public TestObject(){

        }

        public TestObject(String test1){
            this.test1 = test1;

        }

        public String getTest1() {
            return test1;
        }

        public void setTest1(String test1) {
            this.test1 = test1;
        }


    }
```

and here are my methods

```
    // post works fine and object is there ....
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/test")
    public Response post(@BeanParam TestObject test){

        return  PhizzleResponse.response(Response.Status.OK, test, null);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/test/")
    public Response fetch(@BeanParam TestObject activity){




        return PhizzleResponse.response(Response.Status.OK, activity, null);
    }
```

and here is how I am calling the method

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/api/test?token=somevalue&test1=12345
```

again POST is fine and object is populated... with GET object is null entirely.

Comment: Is it still null when you try `localhost:8080/api/test?token=somevalue&test1=12345` from your browser?

Comment: @Egemen yes and POSTMAN

Comment: It's strange that the POJO itself is null. Did you try changing the path? Use '/another_test' for instance. Another thing you might try: add `@NotNull` to your `String test1`, and `@Valid` in front of `@BeanParam`. Then check if you get a validation error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace:

```
@GET
@Path("/test/")
```

With:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
```

Since you are calling the URL without the / at the end.

Comment: Hi @adhesivee that is not it, we use that for all our apis, and have test with and without trailing slash... no effect.